# Ruby/Rails - interate over complex (nested) JSON elements to create objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, activerecord

I'm parsing some JSON from a mixed content source, and with it trying to store it with ActiveRecord.

At the moment I'm using a ton of variables:

```
json['settings']['newsletters']['weekly']
json['info']['address']['city']
```

Or trying to make things a little easier:

```
newsletters = json['settings']['newsletters']
newsletters['weekly']
address = json['info']['address']
address['city']
```

But this is all getting very messy, and not DRY.

I think the better way to do this would be to iterate over each element that is a hash (and therefore 'complex'), and assign it it's own object. This way, I don't have to declare a trillion variables, they can instead be assigned from the context of the JSON input.

So, I can do something like this:

```
user = json['input']
user.settings.newsletters.weekly
user.info.address.city
```

This is inspired by what [ActiveResource](https://github.com/rails/activeresource) documents:

```
# Any complex element (one that contains other elements) becomes its own object:
#
# {"id":1,"first":"Tyler","address":{"street":"Paper St.","state":"CA"}}
tyler = Person.find(1)
tyler.address  # => <Person::Address::xxxxx>
tyler.address.street  # => 'Paper St.'
```

Here is the JSON, reduced for brevity's sake:

```
{
    "username": "robert_fitzsimmonds",
    "emails": [{
        "id_number": 1,
        "address": "robert_fitzsimmonds@yahoo.com",
        "confirmed": false
    }, {
        "id_number": 2,
        "address": "robert_fitzsimmonds@gmail.com",
        "confirmed": true
    }],
    "settings": {
        "marketing": {
            "main": true,
            "weekly": false,
            "daily": false
        },
        "language": "English"
    },
    "info": {
        "address": {
            "line_1": "31 Mole Road",
            "line_2": "",
            "city": "London",
            "post_code": "NE4 5RJ"
        },
        "shared_account": false
    }
}
```

Would such an iteration be the most efficient solution, or is it best to stick to long, messy variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the hash_dot gem if you can https://github.com/adsteel/hash_dot

Comment: This is _precisely_ what I was looking for! Two days of searching RDocs and GitHub, and somehow I didn't stumble upon this Gem. Thanks so much Sana.